# google apps script Horizontal checkboxes like radio buttons (Check/Uncheck)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning,

I'm attempting to implement Checkboxes (Columns O and P), in which if one checkbox is Checked, the other column automatically Unchecks. This will need to be for a several rows.

Once nuance, If a user Inserts a New row, I would like this function to be able to handle the Check/Uncheck function in the new row. For example, if a user Inserts a New row above row 9, the Checkbox feature will also be incorporated for the new row.

I have provided an attachment of the data set in Google Sheets and a code example for one row.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks[image]

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  const cell_checks = ['O5','P5'];
  if(as.getName() == "Planning" && cell_checks.includes(cell) && e.range.isChecked())
  {cell_checks.filter(val=>val!=cell).forEach(c=>as.getRange(c).uncheck())}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this modification:**

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var cellnum = cell.substring(1); 

  const cell_checks = ['O'+ cellnum, 'P'+ cellnum];

  if (as.getName() == "Planning" && cell_checks.includes(cell) && e.range.isChecked()) {

    cell_checks.filter(val => val != cell).forEach(c => as.getRange(c).uncheck())

  }
}
```

I added a new variable `cellnum` to store the `row number` of your `range` then appended it to the `cellchecks` array.

**Sample:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your timely response! Excellent it works as I've needed. Thanks again